# Java: IllegalMonitorStateException on notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

I am trying to call wait() function on the "slp" object, then after 1000 mills wake it up,  but instead of message "Finished ..." I get an "IllegalMonitorStateException" error, after calling notify()

```
class Class1 extends Thread{

 boolean newTxt = false;
private Sleep slp = null;

synchronized public void put(Sleep slp)
{
  thus.slp = slp;
 try{ slp.wait();}catch(Exception x){} 

}
synchronized public void wakeup()
{
  slp.notify();
}
public void run()
{
  while(slp == null ); 
  try{ sleep(1000);}catch(Exception x){} 
  wakeup();

 }
}

class Sleep extends Thread {

Class1 t;
Sleep(Class1 t) {
this.t=t;
}
 public void run() {
 System.out.println("Started");
t.put(this);
System.out.println("Finished after 1000 mills");
 }

}

public class Koord {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Class1 t = new Class1();
 Sleep t1 = new Sleep(t);
 t1.start();
 t.start();
 }
}
```

Comment: Works, but it shows message immediately, not after 1000 mills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be the "owner of the object's monitor" to be able to call `notify` on it.Your methods are all synchronized on `this` and you `notify()` on other objects. Just call `wait()` and `notify()`.

[IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) ,*Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.*

Comment: Ok, so what would I change?

Comment: This is a duplicate of maybe 100 questions here.