# notify giving IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I have very poor knowledge on Multithreading.

I am expecting below Program to run perfectly, but it is not working and produces below Exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.onmobile.client.D.callD(Deadlock.java:76)
    at com.onmobile.client.B.run(Deadlock.java:50)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Java File

```
public class Deadlock {
    C c = new C();
    D d = new D();

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new Deadlock();
    }

    public Deadlock() {
        A a = new A(d,c);
        B b = new B(d,c);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(b);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class A implements Runnable{
    D dObj;
    C cObj;

    A(D obj, C obj1){
        this.dObj = obj;
        this.cObj = obj1;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cObj.callC(dObj);
    }
}



class B implements Runnable{
    D dObj;
    C cObj;

    B(D obj, C obj1){
        this.dObj = obj;
        this.cObj = obj1;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dObj.callD(cObj);
    }
}


class C{
    public synchronized void callC(D dObj){
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dObj.callD1();
    }
    public synchronized void callC1(){
    }   
}

class D{
    public synchronized void callD(C cObj){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        cObj.callC1();
        cObj.notify();
    }

    public synchronized void callD1(){
    }   
}
```

I thought inside callC() method, object of class C ie cObj goes in waiting state and meanwhile control will go to callD() method and there it invokes cObj.notify();
So, this will awake waiting threads waiting on object cObj.

but it is giving me Exception.
I think solution to my problem can be : 
[Java: IllegalMonitorStateException on notify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403189/java-illegalmonitorstateexception-on-notify)

but I am not understanding it correctly.

Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to notify or wait on an object, your thread must own the monitor of the object you act on.

```
public synchronized void callD(C cObj){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    cObj.callC1();
    cObj.notify();
}
```

In this code section you synchronize on the instance of class `D`, as synchronized methods always obtain the monitor of the object they "live" on. But to be able to use `cObj.notify()` you have to obtain the monitor of the `cObj` instance, e.g. by doing

```
synchronized(cObj) {
   cObj.notify();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

when calling object.notify, you must be holding the the lock for that exact object, ie:

```
synchronized(cObj) {
   cObj.notify();
}
```

you should also wrap your wait call in a similar synchronized block:

```
synchronized(cObj) {
   cObj.wait()
}
```

I suggest you read more about it in the Java tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks Omry. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

`notify` on an `Object` should be called only after taking lock or `synchronizing` on that object. So in your case what you need is:

```
class D{
    public void callD(C cObj){ //synchronized not required here
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        synchronize(cObj) {  //synchornize here on cObj  
           cObj.callC1();
           cObj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: in case you are change your code to `synchornize callD` and `synchroniz(cObj)` make sure you on `deadlock` scenario. IMHO only `synchroniz(cObj)` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

To call `notify()` on an object you need to you own this object's lock. In this case to call

```
cObj.notify();
```

you need to wrap it into syncronized block like this:

```
syncronized (cObj)
{
    cObj.notify();
}
```